# change resources according to day full calendar Vue

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I am trying to change the resources according to the day in full calendar. I'm using the resourcetimegridday view. Each resource is a person who should appear only when available. I have a query that returns people who, according to that day, are not on vacation.

When i use eventDidMount, it works only when day has events (the resources changes correctly) but not when there is no event. I cannot find in the full calendar docs, options to accomplish what i expect.

If i use datesSet, I've this error:
Pickup.vue:97 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'calendarOptions')

PickupController.php

```
public function getResources(Request $request){
     
      /**
       * TODO
       * 
       * SELECT
       *   employees.id 
       *    FROM employees
       *    left JOIN appointments
       *    ON appointments.employee_id = employees.id
       *    WHERE employees.id NOT IN (
       *    SELECT appointments.employee_id WHERE (date(appointments.start_time) <= CURDATE() AND date(appointments.finish_time) >= CURDATE()))
       *    AND employees.department_id = 3
       *    GROUP BY employees.id
       */
        $employees = Employee::select('employees.id','employees.name','employees.business_start_time','employees.business_finish_time')
                      ->leftjoin('appointments','employees.id','=','appointments.employee_id')
                      ->whereNotIn('employees.id',
                      DB::table('appointments')->select('appointments.employee_id')->whereDate(('appointments.start_time'),'<=',$request->date)->whereDate(('appointments.finish_time'),'>=',$request->date))
                      ->where('employees.department_id','=',3)
                      ->groupBy('employees.id')
                      ->get();
       

        $resources = [];

        foreach($employees as $employee) {
            $resource = [];
            $resource['id'] = $employee->id;
            $resource['title'] = $employee->name;
            $resource['businessHours']['daysOfWeek'] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            $resource['businessHours']['startTime'] = $employee->business_start_time;
            $resource['businessHours']['endTime'] = $employee->business_finish_time;

            $resources[] = $resource;
        }

        return response()->json($resources);
    }
```

Pickup.vue

```
<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3'
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid"
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import resourceTimeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid'
import scrollGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/scrollgrid'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'
import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es'
import adaptivePlugin from '@fullcalendar/adaptive'
import PickupModal from '../../Components/Modals/PickupModal.vue'
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import { router  } from "@inertiajs/vue3"
import moment from 'moment'
import { reactive } from "vue";
  
  export default {
    name: 'Pickup',
    components: {
      FullCalendar,
      PickupModal,
      AuthenticatedLayout
    },
    emits: {
        'deleteEventResource':{
          id:'',
        },
        'editEventResource':{
          id:'',
        },
        'closeModal':true,
        'saveEventResource':{id:'',},
      },
      props: {
        errors: Object,
        events: Array,
        resources: Array,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showModal: false,
          editing : false,
          newEventResource: {
                title: '',
                content: '',
                date_at: '',
                end_at: '',
                status: '',
                color: '',
                content: ''
            },
    calendarOptions : {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin,interactionPlugin, adaptivePlugin, resourceTimeGridPlugin, scrollGridPlugin ],
        headerToolbar: {
                left: "prev,next today",
                center: "title",
                right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,resourceTimeGridDay,listMonth",
            },
            initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
            locale: esLocale,
            dayMaxEvents: false,
            weekends: true,
            navLinks: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            defaultAllDay: false,
            timeZone: 'Europe/Madrid',
            resources: [],
            dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
            eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
            events: [],
            dayMinWidth: 150,
            stickyFooterScrollbar: true,
            businessHours: [],
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            eventContent: function(eventInfo) {
              return { html: eventInfo.timeText + "<br>" + eventInfo.event.title + "<br>" + eventInfo.event.extendedProps.content }
            },
            
           
            eventDidMount: this.dayDrivers, //works only on days that has events; resources changes
           
            eventMouseEnter: function(info) {info.el.title = info.event.extendedProps.content;},
            datesSet:function (dateInfo){
              let date = dateInfo.startStr.split("T")[0];
axios.get(route('pickups.index',{date:date})).then(({data}) => {
this.$data.calendarOptions.resources = data; //returns Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'calendarOptions')
 });
},
            //lazyFetching: false,
          //  rerenderDelay: 500,
    }
  }
},
beforeMount(){
      const start = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
      this.$data.calendarOptions.resources = {
        url: route('pickups.index',{date:start}),
        method: 'GET',
        failure: error => {
          console.log('tenemos este error: ', error.message);
        }
      },
      this.$data.calendarOptions.events = {
        url: route('pickupsEvents'),
        method: 'GET',
        failure: error => {
          console.log('tenemos este error: ', error.message);
        }
      }
    },
methods: {
    dateClick(arg){
            this.$data.showModal = true;
            this.setModalOpen(arg);
        },
    handleDateClick(clickInfo){
          this.resetModal();
          this.$data.showModal = true;
          this.$emit('dateClick',clickInfo);
        },
        dayDrivers(date){
              
              let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()
              const start = calendarApi.getDate().toISOString().split("T")[0];
              
              axios.get(route('pickups.index',{date:start})).then(({data}) => {
              
              //  calendarApi.addResource(data);
                this.$data.calendarOptions.resources = data;
                //this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi().refetchResources();
              });
            
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a simple solution overriding buttons.

```
customButtons: { 
          prev: { 
            text: "prev", 
            click: () => {           
              let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
              calendarApi.prev();
              this.dayDrivers(calendarApi.getDate().toISOString().split("T")[0]);
            }
          },
          next: { 
            text: "next",
            click: () => {
              let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
              calendarApi.next();
              this.dayDrivers(calendarApi.getDate().toISOString().split("T")[0]);
            }
          },
          today: {
            text: 'today',
            click: () => {
              let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
              calendarApi.today();
              this.dayDrivers(calendarApi.getDate().toISOString().split("T")[0]);
            }
          }
        },
```